# Is this an ordinal regression problem?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data

I have been struggling with ordinal regression for a bit now and would like to ask for some help.

My outcome will be an ordinal variable made up out of 4 groups of which 1=good to 4=bad.

My data consists of all nominal, ordinal and continuous variables and I have cleaned my data, and it is ready to be used. However I bump into some problems.

1. I have a lot of missing data, like for example for a patient I have variable 1 to 12 but not 13. SPSS deletes this case, while I would like to keep it and process it. I have been thinking about replacing the missing data with the mean of the variable but I think I will not have good data then.
2. I have made dummy variables, but I am not sure if I have made them right. For example do I have to make a dummy variable for sex, man/female? 
   How many dummy variables do I have to make for ethnicity? I have European, Arab, Asian, African, and Latin. Do I have to make 5 dummy variables(for each one) or just 4 with European as the standard?
   The statistician whom I have contacted told me that I don’t have to make dummy variables because SPSS makes them for you. but on the internet I found conflicting findings.
3. My outcome should be in 4 groups, 1=good, 2 mild, 3 severe, 4 dead. However I only get outcomes 1 and 4. I think something is wrong with this.

These were my questions, thank you.

Comment: You might do better to break these questions into separate threads. You could also search the site (you can probably find the answer to #2 already).

Comment: Thank you. I mainly ask question 2 because the statistcian who I am in touch with said that I don’t have to make dummy variabeles at all, because SPSS already makes them for you. But on the web I read all these other conflicting reports.

Comment: Perhaps you should include this information into your question to make it clearer.

Comment: The statistican is correct. You don't have to do it yourself. Just provide a factor variable to the regression function!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your response is follows an ordinal likert scale so this would be considered a good candidate for Ordinal Regression.